# Simple way for operator a Number Field in mongoose _ Express, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use the operator in a Number field in mongoose. I did some search and find **$inc** option for this. but now im stuck in the increase or decrease my Number field.

```
let WalletSchemma = mongoose.Schema({

    balance: {
        type      : Number,
        default   : 1,
    },
}:

let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     wallet     :{
        type     : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref      : 'Wallet',
        unique   : true
    },
};
```

here is my query for update :

```
[err, wallet] = await to(User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id:req.user._id},
        {
            $inc : {'wallet.balance': -500}
        }
    ));
```

MongoDB error:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "-500" at path "wallet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` for the wallet field in the `UserSchema` and trying to assign a `Number` to `ObjectId` which causes here Cast error.

You need to embed the `WalletSchema` into `UserSchema` then only you can update the `wallet.balance`.

```
const WalletSchemma = new mongoose.Schema({
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
    }
}:

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     wallet: {
         type: WalletSchema
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because User Schema doesn't have field named balance in wallet field.
Your database schema doesn't support the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Don't need the Wallet Schema instead try this

```
let WalletSchemma = mongoose.Schema({
    balance: {
        type      : Number,
        default   : 1,
    },
}:

let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     wallet     :WalletSchemma
};
```

Comment: The reason is OP has given the ObjectId as a type of the field which causes casting error &  field name issue comes after that.